# Communication between asp.net web pages and windows service

Tags: asp.net

How can I write a windows service which communicates between asp.net web pages?
Windows service is written in c#.NET.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What needs to be communicated between the pages and why do you think a windows service is a good choice?

Comment: I want to run a windows service on a server which continusly accesses a system and updates the value to database.But to configure that system i want to take parameters from users remotely.So

Comment: Please _edit_ the question to add details to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other thing you can do is use some intermediary component like a file or a database to do this too.  The service modifies the file/db, then the ASP.NET page picks that up.  Or vice versa.

This would involve some polling.

Comment: Ya if I follow this approach I have problem in Logging into SQL data base from both windows service and ASP.NET web pages.Could you help me on that??

Comment: When I try launching windows service that connects to sql data base it throws an error saying Failed to create user instance at times.Dont understand why??

Comment: In the ASP.NET site, are you using a database in the App_Data folder, by chance?  The database would have to be attached to SQL Server.  Post the error message, and if you could post your connection string without the user ID/pwd...

Answer (score 4):

The are 2 use cases that come to mind and it is not quite clear from your question which one you need:

- A windows service which sends an HTTP request to an existing ASP.NET application => you could use the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class to achieve this.
- A windows service which is being invoked from an ASP.NET application => in this case you could have a WCF service which is [hosted in a windows service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx) and have the ASP.NET application consume this service.

In both cases you could read about [writing and installing a windows service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412.aspx) in .NET.